# To construct a norm for matrices

Tags: general-topology

The question is that:

For $n\times n$ matrices, could we define a norm,

(1)s.t. 
$$\forall A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{K}), ||A.B||=||B.A||$$

(2)or is there a norm s.t.
$$\forall A\in M_n{(\mathbb{K})}, \forall P\in GL_n(\mathbb{K}), ||P^{-1}AP||=||A||$$

I think the 2 problems have the same idea and both are wrong, but I cannot find a conterexample for neither...

Could someone give a hint?

Thanks~

Comment: Hint for the first one: $AB = 0 \not \implies BA = 0$. Hint for the second one: yes, such a norm exists. Basically, it asks you to define a norm which is independent of any chosen basis. What properties of matrices do you know that are independent of basis -- that is, what properties of linear mappings do you know?

Comment: @MeesdeVries You're probably thinking about the product of eigenvalues (these would lie in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{K}$ presumably ?) would this product then be well-defined ? Or should the norm be a map into $\mathbb{K}$ as well?

Comment: Err, my bad, I actually read $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ instead of $\mathbb K$ before. But something about the field would at least need to be specified, here -- otherwise what is a norm?

Comment: @MeesdeVries actually other exercises of this section say K＝R or C, I think this one also implies and your answer works. Thanks~

Comment: @MeesdeVries I'm sorry I didn't learn well matrices, would you explain why this product exists in R or C(the determinant?) and why it's linear, thanks.